# Error while installing pandas on python 3.4 in windows 10

Tags: python, pandas

Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required.

I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 with Microsoft window SDK 7.1 but still, it's showing the same error

Comment: In not insist, you can install whl for pandas.

Comment: Was the error only `Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required.`?

Comment: @hoseong Jeon yes it says the same